# Need to change flash to some other player

Tags: flash, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have flash code on my website (pasted below, server is renamed)

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.example.COM/swf/player/RadioPlayerFlex4.swf" width="300" height="200">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.example.COM/swf/player/RadioPlayerFlex4.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="flashvars" value="serverHost=www.example.COM&radio=53916&listUrl=http://www.example.COM&defaultTheme=silver&showTheme=false&thinPlayer=true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

This works fine on desktop browsers but on mobile browser this doesn't work at all.
Actually this is streaming audios from `serverHost=www.example.COM&radio=53916&listUrl=http://www.example.COM&defaultTheme=silver&showTheme=false&thinPlayer=true`

Can anyone please give me idea what should I do to get this work on mobile devices?
Do I need to change player?

Comment: HTML5 player, that's what you need

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need to change, flash wont play on most mobile devices and all desktop browsers do support html5 players. By changing the player you also need to change the source, since those players wont play swf files.

Comment: Yes, source files are mp3 files. Can we identify the streaming URL from flash streaming source which I can use in any other HTML5 player. Because I was provided with above pasted code but I don't know what is exact streaming url here.

Comment: You can check out jwplayer. https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406724?b_id=11851&t=616961